# MASM. Getting error "Unmatched macro nesting"

Tags: assembly, masm

I am a beginner in Assembly. I am trying to implement a function that finds the maximum in an array, but getting a error: `fatal error A1008: unmatched macro nesting`

Could you say me what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" int search_max(int* arr, int size);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, -1, 0};
    int a = search_max(arr, 7);
    printf("%d", a);
    return 0;
}




.data
    b byte 4
.code
search_max proc
    mov rax, [rcx]
while:
    cmp rax, [rcx]
    jna assign
    jmp without_assign
assign:
    mov rax, [rcx]
without_assign:
    dec rdx
    jz end_while
    add rcx, b
    jmp while
end_while:
    ret
search_max endp
end
```

Comment: `b byte 4` likely you wanted `b equ 4`. Note that your code is using 64 bit operations while `int` is just 32 bits.

Comment: @Jester This doesn't solve the problem

Comment: That's why it was just a comment.  It solves *other* problems, which the code in your answer still has.  (You only fixed `b`, not the fact that you're doing 8-byte loads overlapping by 4 bytes.  Your C is expecting you to be working on 4-byte elements.  Single-step with a debugger and watch register values.  You want `mov eax, [rcx]` and so on.  Also, `add rcx, 4`; you don't need to and shouldn't put that constant in data memory.)

Comment: peter-cordes, I just started learning assembler. There are many errors in the code, you are right. But I decided to ask this question because I couldn’t run my code. Now the code runs, although it doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 3):

I found the bug. It seems using `while` keyword was a mistake.

```
.data
  b qword 4
.code
search_max proc
   dec rdx
   mov rax, [rcx]
start_while:
   cmp rax, [rcx]
   jbe assign
   jmp without_assign
assign:
   mov rax, [rcx]
without_assign:
   dec rdx
   jz end_while
   add rcx, b
   jmp start_while
end_while:
   ret
search_max endp
end
```